# Is there a way to have the same pattern across all the faces of an icosahedron?

Tags: geometry, topology

This is the scenario: I have an icosahedron, therefore I have 12 vertices and 20 faces.

From the point of view of each vertex he is the center of an "extruded" pentagon, whose triangles are the faces of the icosahedron.

[image: This image was generated by Vladimir Bulatov's Polyhedra Stellations Applet]

Let's say we want to name each of the vertices of each of these triangles from 1 to 3, always in a counterclockwise fashion, imagining that each vertex is not shared among different triangles.

(can't upload the image here for some reason sorry)

https://ibb.co/FmYfRG4

[image]

Is there a way to arrange the naming of the vertices inside each triangle so that every pentagon yields the same pattern of numbers along the five triangles?

As you can see by arranging the vertex names that way there would be the first pentagon with 1,1,1,1,1 but around it other pentagons couldn't have the same pattern.

EDIT: following Andrew Morton's comment I tried to write a possible sequence

[image]

I came up with two sequences of triangles: 1,2,3,1,3 for most pentagons, and 2,2,2,2,2 for the two caps.
I wonder if there is some additional optimization so that I only have one sequence instead of two, or maybe if there's is some mathematical demonstration that makes this impossible.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? You might have what is known an XY problem instead of a problem. If you have a printer then you can easily make your own icosahedron to try it on by searching for "icosahedron net with tabs". Without a printer it will take a few minutes more.

Comment: I have no idea why the second image gives me an error, I tried changing formats.
I didn't think about printing the exploded geometry actually, so I'll try but I think I would have to manually iterate over n combinations, and I would always miss some, I was wondering if there was an established way to solve the problem. The reason why I'm trying to do that is overly complex to explain, in brief I'm trying to find a repetitive structure for the data.

Comment: I think that what you're trying to do is equivalent to colouring the faces of a dodecahedron, where a minumum of four colours is required, so you should be able to do it with vertices numbered (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,1), (4,1,2). Maybe those clever people over on [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) would be of more help.